# `Authentication failure error` when starting the oracle docker container

Tags: oracle, docker, podman

- OS: Mac M1
- Image:  `container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe`
- Docker Driver: Podman (in shell commands below, `docker` is alias of `podman`)

I'm aware that as mentioned in https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/2709 that it's recommended to use `container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.19.0.0` but it doesn't seem to be accessible:

```bash
$ docker pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise       

Trying to pull container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:latest: unable to retrieve auth token: invalid username/password: authentication required
```

So I switched to `container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe` following instruction [here](https://container-registry.oracle.com/ords/f?p=113:4:3378344898456:::4:P4_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY,AI_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_REPOSITORY_NAME,P4_EULA_ID,P4_BUSINESS_AREA_ID:803,803,Oracle%20Database%20Express%20Edition,Oracle%20Database%20Express%20Edition,1,0&cs=3pklUYLpCVZ_vPFKOiyw2XoNtGSeLep2jp7WgyLyqeneE3tSM90HQcKZVQzhuLyJj-f8AXXxj806iiRC-qGWS5A).

And I encountered this error constantly, and with `ORACLE_PWD` set, it still shows the same error.

```bash
$ docker run --name oracle-cont -v $(PWD)/oracle-data:/opt/oracle/oradata \
container-registry.oracle.com/database/express:21.3.0-xe   

WARNING: image platform (linux/amd64) does not match the expected platform (linux/arm64)
Password: su: Authentication failure
```

The thing is, i didn't have the chance to enter any password, but it seems to autocomplete some password, resulting in this auth failure.

Comment: This is a chip architecture and OS that Oracle was never designed to run on. You need a full VM emulating an Intel CPU (or better yet using a real Intel CPU and not an emulation) and running Oracle Linux on which to run your docker container. It won't work on arm64 or Mac OS.